# searchbox as3 not working properly

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash, searchbar, search-box

im having a problem where whatever text or even blank space i put i still go in frame 170, as you see i put 171 frame there, and if i type "therefore" it go in 171 , seems like its working fine its just even i put wrong text it go to frame 170 , i cant find the problem tho,also i dont know if i should make an else statement so if the word is not in the list it will go to other frame, thanks mate

```
 var i:int = 0;
var names:Array = new Array("therefore","disciples","nations","baptizing","father","son","holy spirit");
var frames:Array = new Array("171","170","170","170","170","170","170","170");

button_140.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_MouseClickHandler_4);

function fl_MouseClickHandler_4(event:MouseEvent):void
{
var searchtext:String = searchtext.text.toLowerCase();
findInArray(searchtext);
gotoAndStop(frames[i]);
}

function findInArray(str:String):int
{
for(i=0; i < names.length; i++)
{

        if(names[i] == str)
        {
    return i;
}
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: for loop increases value of "i" no matter if it can find the value or not  and you are using i in this line gotoAndStop(frames[i]);, you should use it like this gotoAndStop(frames[findInArray(searchtext)]);

Comment: hey thank you so much it works very well, but now its having an error if there is no word found in the array list, is there any way to have else statement to make sure the if he input wrong word i will go to different frame that tell word not found? thank you mate

Comment: If it cant find simply return -1 in  findInArray function and check the result if function returns -1 alert to user as word not found

Comment: man im trying to understand it but im really new to flash specially the logical codes, i dont know how will put that if else statement code. can you help me to understand it easier? thank you

Comment: if(findInArray(searchtext) == -1) { /* alert code */ } else{ gotoandstop } , here is the syntax you can google it also .

Comment: i just want to take the user to another frame where theres text that says no word found  if there is no word found in array

Comment: im just gonna put the if else statement in the bottom of my code ?

Comment: sorry i cannot help you more than this rest is up to you its too basic good luck

Comment: ok bro i will figure it out thanks so much for the help tho

Comment: @Bolzano, your 2 comments I upvoted are enough to be a correct answer. Please put them in an answer box so we can give you credit.

Comment: @VC.One the answer is too basic, i just wanted to help jarvis im sure community has no benefit from it. so no need credit thanks for your concern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why you always go to frame 170:

let's see your function `fl_MouseClickHandler_4`:

```
findInArray(searchtext);//string won't be found so "i" would be 7 (the last index in array)
gotoAndStop(frames[i]);//so it goes to frame 170
```

a fix for your code:
the function `fl_MouseClickHandler_4`:

```
function fl_MouseClickHandler_4(event:MouseEvent):void
{
var searchtext:String = searchtext.text.toLowerCase();
var index:int=findInArray(searchtext);

if(index==-1){
    //do something when frame not found
}
else{
    gotoAndStop(frames[index]);
}
```

the function `findInArray`:

```
function findInArray(str:String):int
{
for(i=0; i < names.length; i++)
{

    if(names[i] == str)
    {
return i;//return the found index
}
}
return -1;//return -1 if nothing found
}
```

I Hope this helps...

**Edit:**

You don't need to make a function to find a value in your array. You can use `Array` class built-in method `indexOf()` to find the index of an item in an array: see the [**AS3 manual**](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#indexOf()) for more info.

```
theArray.indexOf(theValue);
```

returns the index of theValue. if theValue is not in theArray, returns -1.

Test this example below :

```
//# declare variables outside of function (make once & re-use) 
var searchtext:String = "";
var index:int = 0; 

//# after updating searchtext string with user-text then run function below

function fl_MouseClickHandler_4(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    searchtext = searchtext.text.toLowerCase();
    index = names.indexOf(searchtext); //test with "holy spirit"

    if(index == -1)
    {
        trace("index is : -1 : No match found");
        //do something when frame not found
    }
    else
    {
        trace("index is : " + index + " ::: result is : " + (frames[index]) );
        gotoAndStop( frames[index] );
    }
}
```

Comment: Sir you are a hero, ok i will try this when i got home. thanks so much mate!  cheers!

Comment: Hey sir so should i replace this findInArray(searchtext); to this theArray.indexOf(theValue); ?

Comment: @JarvisLorenzD.PAlad see if the edit with code helps you.

Comment: Ay sir i ll try it too once i go home thanks much brother!

Comment: @JarvisLorenzD.PAlad You're welcome. I'm glad I could help you again.

Comment: hi hitman it works like a miracle! thanks, may  i ask once again if i can make the word that i search highlighted so they can notice it. thanks!

Comment: @JarvisLorenzD.PAlad first: I didn't understand what did you mean about highlighting the word. and second: better to ask it in a new question. isn't it better?